# Cannot properly add directory to PATH with Apache Jena

Tags: sparql, jena, arq

I am trying to set up Jena through Windows command line but am running into this error:

```
C:\Users\User>SET JENA_HOME=C:\Users\User\Documents\SPARQL\jena-4.10.0

C:\Users\User>SET PATH=%PATH%;%JENA_HOME%\bat

C:\Users\User>sparql.bat --version
'sparql.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What I am expecting to happen is what the Apache website states: "This command will simply print the versions of Jena and ARQ used in your distribution, all the tools support the `--version` option." This will indicate that the tools have been properly set up.

I tried to change the path in command line directly and through the Environment Variables settings in the Windows Advanced Systems Settings to add the Jena directory to my machine's PATH there as well. Additionally, I've gone through the Apache website a million times, combed through google/forums and even tried Chat GPT which got stuck circling on the same issue of a library for some reason.

I have been trying for a day and a half to fix this with no luck. If anyone could help me troubleshoot I would be so grateful, looking forward to hearing what I am missing here!

-Terry

Comment: Does C:\Users\User\Documents\SPARQL\jena-4.10.0 exists? What files are in it?

Comment: Yes. Inside of it are the files extracted from the Jena download.